# Updating gps locations in a uitable view in the cell.detailTextLabel.text problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, gps, cell, core-location

I am working on a Core Location based application which displays the name of the place you are heading towards in the `UITableView` text and display how far away from the location you are from in the `cell.detailTextLabel.text`.

I have GPS delegate that updates the location and I set a Core location getter and setter and try to use that location to set the `cell.detailTextLabel.text` each time I get an update.

But my problem lies in scrolling the UITableView. When i click on a cell is goes to where I want it to but if I try to scroll the view to see all the cells the app crashes and issues a bad access error. I don't know where there is a bad access in the location update or if there is a better way to get the gps locations into the `cell.detailTextLabel.text` and update it better than get the new location and reloading the data.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: When you run in debug mode, what does the call stack look like when your application crashes?

Comment: I a getting a -[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5dd5e40 and i dont know why. I have a CLLocation called newestLocation which is set when the didUpdateLocation returns a new location. but in the setting of the cells in the table view I am computing the new distances and I get that error on the line CLLocatinDistance distance = [newestlocation distanceFromLocation:destination];

Comment: I finally figured it out. I was setting one instance of the newestLocation to the number of destinations in the tableview but I guess you can't do that. So I maintain an array of allocated newestLocations and update that array as new location come in.

Comment: Hi, Dan i am also trying to build similar sort of application but i am interested in showing nearby specific places. Can you please let me know who can i show these places in table view. i can get current location coordinates. I really appriciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you have an error in your UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate methods. If you don't get the count of sections and cells right or if you don't return a valid cell as required you will always crash. Some NSLogs in these functions might help you to spot any problems as they occur.

Next make sure to set the environment variable (doubleclick the  app executable, select arguments) and add "NSZombieEnabled" with value YES. If you are releasing something that your table later uses, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is the result and this will cause a debugger breakpoint rather than just a mysterious crash - with a stack trace you should be able to easily find the problem.

You're using reloadData to refresh the table view cell?